# Does GHC optimize the monoid operation over mempty?

Tags: haskell, optimization, ghc

If I write an instance of `Monoid` with a horrible complexity for its operation `(<>)`, will GHC know that

```hs
mempty <> x = x
x <> mempty = x
```

and avoid computing `(<>)` ?

I'm also interested in *how* you got that information, and, if this optimization does not exits, whether this could be done or has been discussed previously.

Comment: In the Monoid implementation (https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.4-latest/docs/html/libraries/base-4.5.1.0/src/Data-Monoid.html), `mempty` is declared INLINE so I guess there is probably no optimization, but I'd still be interested in any insight, since I don't understand really well how GHC optimization works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a sketch for how a rewrite rule can accomplish what you've layed out in [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77444600/does-ghc-optimize-the-monoid-operation-over-mempty#comment136532312_77444680):

```
{-# LANGUAGE UnicodeSyntax #-}

module RewriteMempty where

data Big = Big String

instance Semigroup Big where
  Big s <> Big t = Big . reverse $ reverse s++reverse t
instance Monoid Big where
  mempty = Big ""

class Inflatable a where
  inflate :: a -> Big

instance Inflatable Double where
  inflate = Big . show . replicate 100000

{-# NOINLINE poppedBalloon #-}
poppedBalloon :: Big
poppedBalloon = mempty
{-# RULES "OmitPopped" ∀ x . poppedBalloon <> x = x #-}

instance Inflatable Int where
  {-# INLINE inflate #-}
  inflate _ = poppedBalloon

big :: Big
big = inflate (pi :: Double)

debig :: Big -> String
debig (Big s) = show $ length s

{-# SPECIALIZE busy :: Int -> String #-}

busy :: Inflatable a => a -> String
busy x = debig $ inflate x <> big
```

Comment: This is great, I'm always amazed with Haskell's richness, I had no idea any of that was possible, thank you so much ! Eventually, I'll probably go for simpler optimizations such as the ones suggested in the comments, but this is definitely what I had in mind when I asked the question.

Comment: @141592653 unfortunately it's a bit of a dark art how to get the rules to actually fire and in an order that achieves the intended results. I'd definitely always do as much optimisation as possible within the normal Haskell code, before resorting to rewrite rules.

Answer (score 6):

No, for several reasons. First, you don't have to write lawful Semigroup instances. `x <> y = x` is a valid definition as far as the compiler is concerned, and it has to generate code that matches the behavior you specify. So there can be no such optimization for *every* Semigroup.

GHC also can't in general know whether some value is equal to `mempty` or not, except by testing it, which it could only do given an `Eq` instance. But it's not going to go inserting implicit `(==)` tests around every Semigroup operation just to avoid calling your `(<>)` implementation. If *you* have a specific Semigroup type that you think will perform better if you check for `mempty` before doing the main work of `(<>)`, *you* can insert that in the Semigroup instance yourself.

Comment: Regarding the first part of the answer, `mempty` is a member of the `Monoid` class, and I'm specifically talking about `mempty`, not any other member of the semigroup. So I'm talking about an optimizations for Monoids, not for Semigroups. I updated the question to make that clearer

Comment: Regarding the second part, GHC actually *could* know in some cases that a value is `mempty` *if* `mempty` wasn't inlined. It then *could* when seeing stuff like `mempty <> x` simply replace it with `x`. Am I completely wrong or is this something that actually could work, in theory ?

Comment: Anyway, I like your suggestion of using an optimized instance, it actually helped a lot in the practical case that raised this question

Comment: @141592653 GHC could easily replace `mempty <> x` with `x` if it appears literally in the source code. In fact you can make that happen by adding a rewrite-rule. But it's pretty useless, because you could just change that right in the source yourself! For cases where it might actually be useful, the check won't be as straightforward, in fact Rice's theorem kicks in. Of course it can be possible to check it at runtime, but in that case you should just include this check in your `Semigroup` instance.

Comment: @leftaroundabout That makes sense. But I'm not sure it'd be useless. Here is the practical I was asking the question : 
I have this line of code `renderer (shiftTo x <> d)` in a project I'm working on. I'm not going to explain what it does, but what I can say is that
1 ) the `<>` featured here will be called millions of times, so it's critical
2 ) `shiftTo` is a function defined from a class, and often it will be implemented
as `shiftTo x = mempty`. 

Now if `shiftTo` is inlined and the rewrite rule exists, that could be a huge boost!

Comment: @141592653 Sounds like perhaps your class ought to have another method `shiftObject`, with default implementation `shiftObject x d = shiftTo x <> d`, which the `mempty`-instances can implement as `shiftObject _ d = d`.

Comment: That's a greatidea, theanks a lot !